# InDesign script to list hyperlinks in active document

Tags: adobe-indesign, batch-processing, indesign-scripting, javascript

I am trying to get a list of hyperlinks from my document printed in the console or output to text file. This is what i'm playing with:

```
for (k=0; k<app.activeDocument.hyperlinks.length-1; k++)
{
    $.writeln(app.activeDocument.hyperlinks.item[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More than one error there, I'm afraid. "Hyperlink" is not covered in the latest version of Adobe's own Scripting guide (which would be "Adobe InDesign CS6 Scripting Guide: JavaScript" on http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html), but that's no reason to just 'try' things. The ExtendScript Toolkit Editor has a Help of its own – the "Object Model Viewer" under "Help" – in which you can find `hyperlink` and all of its properties, but I prefer this version of the same data: [Hyperlink](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Hyperlink.html).

You have the following problems:

1. `app.activeDocument.hyperlinks.item[k]`: `item` is not an *array*, it is a *function* (see [Hyperlinks.item()](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Hyperlinks.html#item)).
2. When you correctly ask for the `item`, you will get an `[Object Hyperlink]` because it is an object with multiple properties.
3. .. and the property you are interested in is `destination`:

   > The text, page, or URL that the hyperlink points to. Can return: HyperlinkTextDestination, HyperlinkPageDestination, HyperlinkExternalPageDestination, HyperlinkURLDestination or ParagraphDestination.
4. .. more specifically, since hyperlinks can point to lots of different objects, the `destination` *must* be of type `HyperlinkURLDestination`;
5. .. which is an object of its own, again with lots of properties (see [HyperlinkURLDestination](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_HyperlinkURLDestination.html)); and you presumably want to get the `destinationURL`.

Putting all of that together, the following script

```js
for (k=0; k<app.activeDocument.hyperlinks.length; k++)
{
    if (app.activeDocument.hyperlinks[k].destination instanceof HyperlinkURLDestination)
        $.writeln (app.activeDocument.hyperlinks[k].destination.destinationURL);
}
```

will list out all external URLs. Writing to a file is straightforward as well:

```
writeFile = File(Folder.myDocuments+'/urls.txt');
writeFile.open("w");

for (k=0; k<app.activeDocument.hyperlinks.length; k++)
{
    if (app.activeDocument.hyperlinks[k].destination instanceof HyperlinkURLDestination)
        writeFile.writeln (app.activeDocument.hyperlinks[k].destination.destinationURL);
}
writeFile.close();
writeFile.execute();
```